# How do I install Gimp 2.7.3?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, gimp

I'm trying to install gimp 2.7.3 from the repository of launchpad ppa:matthaeus123/mrw-gimp-svn, but when I try to install, it installs the package gimp with the 2.6 version instead of the 2.7, but the others libraries are installed with 2.7.3. There's an error? How I can install it?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` after adding the PPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a system can point to many archives which contain various versions of the same package. By default the highest version is installed. To select a different version of the package, add "=(version)" (without the parentheses) to the end of "sudo apt-get install ". For example, let's say you want to install package "trojanrabbit" version 2 and it is not the currently highest available version:

```
sudo apt-get install trojanrabbit=2
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can see from the above image that gimp and babl packages failed to build.

You should contact the author of the PPA to see if he can resolve this problem.