# Can i install Gimp 2.7?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, gimp

I am trying to install Gimp 2.7 on my Ubuntu 11.10 64bit.

I used the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:matthaeus123/mrw-gimp-svn 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

This issue is that this works fine for the standard 32bit OS, but when using 64bit Gimp does not upgrade and there is no force upgrade option. Even running sudo apt-get upgrade, only upgrades gimp-data, but not the actual Gimp program.

The process also remove Gimp 2.6, but no upgrade available.

Is it possible to install the i386 version easily, or will this cause other issues for me and defeat why I am using 64bit on this PC.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I then tried sudo apt-get upgrade, but still only upgraded gimp-data and not the main gimp application....

Comment: posibble duplicate -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/68001/how-do-i-install-gimp-2-7 and this http://askubuntu.com/questions/64569/how-do-i-install-gimp-2-7-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this guide:

http://blog.bloke.com/2010/06/howto-build-gimp-2-7-1-from-source-step-by-step-ubuntu/

but used babl version 0.1.4, gegl version 0.1.6, and gimp version 2.7.3.

You also might need to use `sudo make install` instead of `make install`

Comment: Thanks, I will try. I haven't had much success using the 'make install' command. Often the instruction is a bit vague... Cheers

Comment: The tutorial refers to 10.04LTS, and all the dependencies refer to that release too. Not sure if it will work on my release, I don't want to screw my laptop, just got it working well :-) Do you know if it will automatically install the latest dependencies, etc for my release? Sorry, when it comes to building from source I don't have a lot of experience. Thanks

Comment: I don't know, but it worked for me on 11.10

Comment: But make sure to change the version numbers of babl, gegl, and gimp to the ones I specified in the answer.